# Randomly generated coordinates

Tags: function-construction, random, conditional

I want to code that will do the following:

> Write a Mathematica function called `randomHop` that takes as its argument a list containing two coordinates x and y; your definition should begin
>
> ```
> randomHop[{x_, y_}] :=
> ```
>
> The function should then generate a random integer r equal to 1 or 2 (this should be locally scoped), and then
>
> - if r is equal to 1, return {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}} . {x, y};
> - if r is 2, return {{-0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, -0.5}} . {x, y} + {1.0, 0}.

I have so far tried

```
randomHop[{x_, y_}] := (
  r = RandomInteger[{1, 2}]
  If[r == 1, Return[{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}.{x, y}], 
  Return[{{-0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, -0.5}} . {x, y} + {1.0, 0}]])
```

but it's not working, and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does it work if you add a `;` right after `r = RandomInteger[{1, 2}]` ?

Comment: No it doesn't @Nasser

Answer (score 7):

To localize `r`, I would use `Module`. Otherwise, the only changes needed are inserting a missing semicolon and getting rid of the unnecessary `Return` calls.

```
ClearAll[randomHop];
randomHop[{x_,y_}]:=Module[{
    r
},
    r=RandomInteger[{1,2}];
    If[r==1,
        {{0.5,0.5},{0.5,0.5}}.{x,y},
        {{-0.5,-0.5},{0.5,-0.5}}.{x,y}+{1,0}
    ]
];

SeedRandom[1];

NestList[randomHop,{1,2},10];
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {-0.5, -0.5}, {1.5, 0.}, {0.75, 0.75}, {0.25, 0.}, {0.125, 0.125}, 
>  {0.125, 0.125}, {0.125, 0.125}, {0.875, 0.}, {0.4375, 0.4375}, {0.5625, 0.}}
> ```

Visualize the path like:

```
NestList[randomHop,{1,2},10]//ListLinePlot
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Ganyo10. Your comment is opaque. My answer shows it worked fine form me. What went wrong when you ran my code in on your system?

Comment: @Ganyo10 have you tried copying each statement in a separate cell? Maybe some parsing issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
randomHop[{x_, y_}] := If[RandomInteger[{1, 2}] == 1, {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}.{x, y}, 
    {{-0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, -0.5}}.{x, y} + {1.0, 0}]
```

also works.